# Custom image size doesn't work

Tags: theme-development, images

I'm developing my own theme. I'm trying to remove the default WordPress image sizes medium, large and full. I also want my own image size, `vividflow-full-width`. I'm using [this Sumtips tutorial](http://sumtips.com/2011/12/custom-image-sizes-in-wordpress.html).

At the `after_setup_theme`, this is runt:

```
add_image_size( 'vividflow-full-width', 682, 9999, true );
```

And at the `image_size_names_choose` action hook:

```
unset( $sizes['medium']);
unset( $sizes['large']);
unset( $sizes['full'] );

$myimgsizes = array(
    "vividflow-full-width" => __( "Full width" )
);

return array_merge($sizes, $myimgsizes);
```

However, at the insert media screen, I only see the option to insert a thumbnail. What's going wrong?

I'm sure the functions both codes are in are runt. I don't see any errors in my error log, nor get I any notices when setting `WP_DEBUG`.

Comment: Are you unsetting 'small' also? If so, read the final comment of the tutorial.

Comment: No, `$sizes` isn't empty, I don't remove the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom size will only show up as an option if the selected image exists at those dimensions. So, have you uploaded any images since adding the new image size to functions.php? If not, then you won't see the vividflow option.

You could always run regenerate thumbnails so bring your older images up to date.